# Optimizing by caching results of calculations to string variables

Tags: c#, optimization

I have several classes which will have calculated members exposed to the UI. I'm trying to optimize such that the readout only gets a fresh value when needed.

For instance, I have a Container which can hold Items. Items have UnitMass, UnitSize, UnitCount, etc. Items also calculate their TotalMass (UnitMass x UnitCount), TotalSize, etc. Containers calculate their TotalContentMass, TotalContentSize, and so on by summing the respective members of their contents.

A Container owner might have visible readouts of TotalContentMass, etc. for a hundred containers at any time. Any number any container reads might be changing 30x per second, or might remain the same for hours on end.

```
[Container 1] TotalContentMass: 218 | AvailableMass: 1991
     [Item 1] Units: 5  | TotalMass: 50
     [Item 2] Units: 3  | TotalMass: 96
     ...
[Container 2] TotalContentMass: 944 | AvailableMass: 53
     [Item 1] Units: 12 | TotalMass: 16
     [Item 2] Units: 21 | TotalMass: 488
     ...
...
```

So for these kinds of "TotalX" members, I thought I'd have a field which stored the ToString result of the calculation, and use that string for most UI purposes. I'd rely on event handling to keep the string updated.

```
class Item
{
    int _unitCount;
    int _unitMass;
    string _totalMassText;
    int _unitSize;
    string _totalSizeText;

    ...

    public TotalMass { get { return _unitMass * _unitCount; } }
    public TotalMassText { get { return _totalMassText; } }

    public TotalSize { get { return _unitSize * _unitCount; } }
    public TotalSizeText { get { return _totalSizeText; } }

    public UnitCount 
    { 
        get { return _unitCount; } 
        set { 
                _unitCount = value; 
                OnUnitCountChanged();
            } 
    }

    ...

    UpdateTotals()
    {
        _totalMassText = TotalMass.ToString();
        _totalSizeText = TotalSize.ToString();
        ...
    }
}
```

And the same for Container, and so on.

Is this premature or micro-optimization? Does the compiler take care of this sort of thing in the first place? If not, is this a fairly standard approach?

Comment: No, the compiler does not automatically cache anything here. Yes, it's a standard approach to cache results if the result is expensive to calculate. But creating the strings is not very expensive, so I'd say it's a micro-optimization until a profiler says otherwise. It might even be beneficial to create the strings only on demand and not immediately when the value changes.

Comment: @dtb:Thanks. If you repost this as an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the compiler does not automatically cache anything here. Yes, it's a standard approach to cache results if the result is expensive to calculate. But creating the strings is not very expensive, so I'd say it's a micro-optimization until a profiler says otherwise. It might even be beneficial to create the strings only on demand and not immediately when the value changes.